# how to fetch the data from dictionary using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an app for kids app.

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"A":@[@"Apple",@"Ant",.....],
                       @"B":@[@"Ball",@"Bat",.....],
                       @"C":@[@"Call",@"Cat",.....],
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       };
```

how to fetch the data apple and ant

Comment: I recommend reading the docs to understand basics of Cocoa Collections: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html

Comment: but i not understand ,how to get the value apple,ant ,ball,bat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSDictionary read data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178962/nsdictionary-read-data)

Comment: like this: [[data objectForKey:"A"] objectAtIndex:0] will give you "Apple"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *dataFromA = data[@"A"];
//Apple and Ant
NSString *apple = dataFromA[0];
NSString *ant = dataFromA[1];
//or
NSString *apple = data[@"A"][0];
NSString *ant = data[@"A"][1];
```